# What is Federated , Certified Authentication?

Tags: authentication

I was completing an infosec report and came across this.

***Does the APP support end-user authentication?  Federated, Certified, other?***

I wanted to have some clarification on the terms.

From what I understand

- **End-user authentication** means having user auth capabilities
- **Federated** means that the authentication system can be cross domain?(unsure)
- Don't know about **Certified**.

Where would third party auth providers like Google come in? Also what about having an inbuilt simple email password auth be called here?

Comment: Federated is just a fancy word for grouped, but i don't know what that means in this context either

Answer (score 1):

Answering the part "what is federated authentication"

I assume that the author means using authentication in a [Fediverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fediverse) (aka Federation-Universe) which means you create an account at one provider and can use that login at an other provider (of the same fediverse)

Example: you have registered at "SomeProvider" getting the username  @PeterSmith@SomeProvider. you can login to "AnOtherProvider" using your @PeterSmith@SomeProvider account.

Certified authentication means using a certificate (similar to ssl-certificate)